# Synchronized блок не работает

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Есть 10 одновременно работающих потоков, которые добавляют один элемент (в синхронизированом блоке) в `LinkedList`. Но, в итоге, добавляется не 10 элеметов, а меньше. Возможно, я не совсем понимаю работу `synchronized` блока. Может кто-нибудь объяснить причину неправильной работы и предложить способ синхронизации получше?

Код потока:

```
import java.util.LinkedList; 

public class TestThread extends Thread {

    private LinkedList<String> lks;

    public TestThread(LinkedList<String> lks) {
        this.lks = lks;
    }

    public void run() {     
        synchronized(lks) {
            lks.add("a");
        }
    }               
}
```

Код главного метода:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String []args) throws SQLException, IOException, ExecutionException {   
        List<TestThread> t = new ArrayList<TestThread>();       
        LinkedList<String> lks =new LinkedList<String>();   

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            t.add(new TestThread(lks)); 
        }

        t.parallelStream().forEach(x->x.start());   
        System.out.println(lks.size());         
    }
}
```

Comment: Кстати, старайтесь делать пример минимальным. Метод `getBytes()` здесь явно лишний.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`synchronized` отрабатывает корректно, но вы не дожидаетесь окончания работы всех тредов. Если сделать `join()` всем тредам, в списке всегда будет 10 элементов.

```
t.parallelStream().forEach(x -> x.start());
t.forEach(x -> {
    try {
        x.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});

System.out.println(lks.size());
```